# Is it possible to create a type that force to return the `typeof` statement in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

For example, I want to create a type that make some like below.

```js
class C1 {}

type TGenericType<T> = typeof T;

let test: TGeneticType<C1>; //=> typeof C1
```

I don't want to have to pass a `typeof` explicitly as a generic, like below

```js
let test: TGeneticType<typeof C1>
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCCM0DeBfAsAKEwFwJ4AcBTaAFQHFCA7QgJwEtgSDCAeEgPmgF5SBuTTMAD2lCNmjZCYgFykK1eo2YsE7XtCA this ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler no. That returns just `C1`. I need to return `type of C1`.

Comment: It is not possible. The TypeScript `typeof` operator accepts a *value* as its argument, not a *type*, but type aliases like `TGenericType` (or maybe `Genetic`?) can only take *type* parameters, not *value* parameters.  So `typeof T` where `T` is a type parameter is a category mistake.  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yeah. That totally answers my question. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to re-implement or wrap the [TypeScript `typeof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) as a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type.

The TypeScript `typeof` operator takes a *value* such as a variable or property as an argument, and evaluates to the TypeScript type of that value.  If you write `typeof C1`, then `C1` is interpreted as the value named `C1`, which is the constructor of the `C1` class.

But generic type parameters, like the `T` in the `TGenericType<T>` [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases), represent *types* and not values.  So `typeof T` does not make sense because `T` is itself a type. Hence the compiler error:

```
type TGenericType<T> = typeof T; // error!
// -------------------------> ~
// 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

---

If you try to fix this, you'll either find yourself writing

```
type TGenericType<T> = T;
let test: TGenericType<typeof C1> = C1;
```

which is no better than just writing `typeof C1` to start with; or, you'll decide that what you really want is for `TGenericType<C1>` to produce a [constructor type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) where `C1` is the instance, which looks like this:

```
type TGenericType<T> = new () => T;
let test: TGenericType<C1> = C1; // okay
```

but that doesn't actually have anything to do with the `C1` value, so while you could use this to construct new `C1` instances, you would lose track of any static properties:

```
class C1 { 
    static foo = 1;
    bar = 2;
}
new C1().bar; // okay
new test().bar; // okay
C1.foo; // okay
test.foo // error
```

It depends on your use case which of these you want to pursue, or whether you want to give up entirely.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCCM0De0BQ0PQgFzNglsNAGYD2p0AvNPANzqYBGYATldAEz0C+qq2ATwAOAU2gAVAOIiAdiJaFxwkQB5xAPnaDRpYhNrQA9IejyWpFgEJUx6AFoHjp85dPNAPxsmA5OO-RSGRABaBYRYnkYbAowaG0RABpoRgBXbGh8GEYRfBkAc2gUiBEAE2hIcugANzAQFLEAC3kRADo+EBF07BEcAC4JaTkFYCVRFQR1A2NKTXjdOHg+GTAAWx6hMGAxAFVijqhkBgx4gdl5RWU1TWpxekxoDq6e7H6pM+HR1Tm9CfYEHiWq3WmzEAFkwAJsod7ic3kMLmMNOw5AB3aAACgAlFRNLcjg9OnFnq9BucRpdftR-kYTNgGploCiLABrLJpfGohZYlrMFhTEykZkQjkiNHdHDc3n8gJCgT4hAtMikaWC4Uw56K8g00wscwsVDcIA)